# Application Insights - Why do custom dependencies track from the wrong parent?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-application-insights

We have an aspnetcore project which features a couple of Azure Functions and an API that has a dependency on Redis.

Using [code similar to this article](https://github.com/Azure/aspnet-redis-providers/issues/51) we have got the Redis calls tracking into Application Insights (great) however they are logging to the Application Insights instance rather than the system calling them e.g. the API (see a screenshot of the chart below).

We have `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();` in the Startup.

Do we need to set something to relate the parent container app and the dependency some how?

Our tracking looks like this:

```
_telemetryClient.TrackDependency(_telemetryType, _telemetryTarget, method, key, startTime, elapsed, string.Empty, true);
```

[image]

Comment: So, the api makes a call to the redis cache, but the dependency telemetry isn't tied up to the api request, is that an accurate description?

Comment: Yes sounds about right @PeterBons, on the graph above the green circle with `4` in it is the Application Insights instance the other two green circles are the API and a WWW instance that actually make the calls

Answer (score 0):

If you want the dependency telemetry to be linked to the request you need to somehow tell what the parent operation is. A detailed overview can be found in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation#data-model-for-telemetry-correlation)

You can start a new dependency trace by using `StartOperation`. This way, the operation is linked to the parent operation (the request in the example below) so the `operation_id` and `operation_parentId` are set automatically:

```cs
[HttpGet("/api/endpoint")]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Endpoint()
{
    ...

    
    using (var op = _telemetryClient.StartOperation<DependencyTelemetry>("Redis")
    {
        // call redis

        op.Telemetry.Success = true;
    }

    ...
}
```

Another example can be found [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/custom-operations-tracking#outgoing-dependencies-tracking).

If you take a look at [the linked code](https://github.com/Azure/aspnet-redis-providers/issues/51), it should be easy to modify to use `StartOperation`.